# Multiple Mat-tabs with pagination

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular5

Need to create 2 mat-table elements on page, but pagination didn't work...

```
<mat-table #table1 [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort id="jobs">
<mat-table #table2 [dataSource]="refDataSource" matSort id="errors">

@ViewChild('table1', {read: MatPaginator}) errPaginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild('table1', {read: MatSort}) errSort: MatSort;

@ViewChild('table2', {read: MatPaginator}) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild('table2', {read: MatSort}) sort: MatSort;
```

help me pls with this, thank you in advance

Comment: can you try to post your code on stackblitz so we can help you out.